# How to delete entire column in Excel sheet and write updated data in new excel file using Perl?

Tags: perl

I am new to Perl. I have excel file say "sample.xls" which looks like follows. 
[Sample.xls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1aBnK.png)

There are about data of 1000 rows like this. I want to parse this file and write it in another file say "output.xls" with following output format.

[output.xls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qM9QZ.png)
I have written a script in perl, however, it doesn't give me the exact output the way I want. Also, looks like the script is not very efficient. Can anyone guide me how I can improve my script as well as have my output as shown in "output.xls" ??

Here's the Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl –w

use strict;
use warnings;
use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel;
use Spreadsheet::WriteExcel;
use Spreadsheet::WriteExcel::Chart;


# Read the input and output filenames.
my $inputfile  = "path/sample.xls";
my $outputfile = "path/output.xls";

if ( !$inputfile || !$outputfile ) {
    die( "Couldn't find file\n" );
}

my $parser      = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel->new();
my $inwb = $parser->parse( $inputfile );

if ( !defined $inwb ) {
    die "Parsing error: ", $parser->error(), ".\n";
}

my $outwb = Spreadsheet::WriteExcel->new( $outputfile );


my $inws  = $inwb->worksheet( "Sheet1" );
my $outws = $outwb->add_worksheet("Sheet1");
my $out_row       = 0;

my ( $row_min, $row_max ) = $inws->row_range();
my ( $col_min, $col_max ) = $inws->col_range();

my $format = $outwb->add_format(
center_across => 1,
bold => 1,
size => 10,
border => 4,
color => 'black',
border_color => 'black',
align => 'vcenter',
);


$outws->write(0,0, "Item Name", $format);
$outws->write(0,1, "Spec", $format);
$outws->write(0,2, "First name", $format);
$outws->write(0,3, "Middle Name", $format);
$outws->write(0,4, "Last Name", $format);
$outws->write(0,5, "Customer Number", $format);
$outws->write(0,6, "Age", $format);
$outws->write(0,7, "Units", $format);

my $col_count = 1;
#$row_min = 1;
for my $inws ( $inwb->worksheets() ) {
    my ( $row_min, $row_max ) = $inws->row_range();
    my ( $col_min, $col_max ) = $inws->col_range();

    for my $in_row ( 2 .. $row_max ) {

        for my $col (  0 .. 0 ) {


            my $cell = $inws->get_cell( $in_row, $col);

            my @fields = split /_/, $cell->value();
                next unless $cell;


            $outws->write($in_row,$col, $cell->value());
            $outws->write($in_row,$col+1, $fields[1]);
        }
    }   

    for my $in_row ( 2 .. $row_max ) {

        for my $col (  1 .. 1 ) {

            my $cell = $inws->get_cell( $in_row, $col);

            my @fields = split /_/, $cell->value();
                next unless $cell;


            #$outws->write($in_row,$col+1, $cell->value());
            $outws->write($in_row,$col+1, $fields[0]);
            $outws->write($in_row,$col+2, $fields[1]);
            $outws->write($in_row,$col+3, $fields[2]);
            $outws->write($in_row,$col+4, $fields[3]);
        }
    }   

    for my $in_row ( 2 .. $row_max ) {

        for my $col (  2 .. 2 ) {

            my $cell = $inws->get_cell( $in_row, $col);

            my @fields = split /_/, $cell->value();
                next unless $cell;


            $outws->write($in_row,6, $cell->value());
        }
    }   

    for my $in_row ( 2 .. $row_max ) {

        for my $col (  3 .. 9 ) {

            my $cell = $inws->get_cell( $in_row, $col);

            next unless $cell;


        }
    }   

    for my $in_row ( 2 .. $row_max ) {
        for my $col ( 10 .. 10 ) {

            my $cell = $inws->get_cell( $in_row, $col );

            next unless $cell;


            $outws->write($in_row,7, $cell->value());

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and the Perl tag. This is a pretty good first question. :) Having the files directly would have been nice though. You can [edit] the question to add them if you want. Also make sure to take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: If I see it correctly, the difference in your current output and the expected output is that you want it sorted by `Item Name`, and with blanks between the different item names. Next time, include that information in the question please. What about the efficiency? Why do you think it's not efficient? It looks like it is doing what it should already, and the user of the Excel file could easily add a sorting function in Excel. That requires about two to three clicks to sort it the way you want. At $work, I would tell the business people to sort it themselves and be happy they get XLS, not CSV.:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get your output sorted, you need to collect all the information first before you are writing it out. Right now, you are doing a bit of jumping back and forth between rows and columns.

Here are some changes I would make to get it sorted, and make it more efficient (to read).

- Create a data structure `$data` outside of your loop to store all the information.
- If there is only one worksheet, you don't need to loop over sheets. Just work with one sheet.
- Loop over the lines.
- Inside that loop, use the code you have to parse the individual fields to just parse them. No `2..2` loops. Just a bunch of statements.

  ```
  my @item_fields = split /_/, $inws->get_cell( $in_row, 0 ) || q{};
  my @name_fields = split /_/, $inws->get_cell( $in_row, $col ) || q{};
  ```
- Store them in `$data` per item.

  ```
  push @{ $data } = [ $item_fields[0], ... ];
  ```
- Done with the loop. Open the output file.
- Loop over `$data` with a `sort` and write to the output file.

  ```
  foreach my $row (sort { $a->[0] cmp $b->[0] } @{ $data } ) { ... }
  ```
- Done.

I suggest you read up on [`sort`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html) and also check out [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html) and [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) to learn more about references (data structures).